# Need to change citation from [1] ,[2] to [1.1][1.2] depending on the chapter

Tags: natbib, subdividing

References in chapter 1 should appear as

> [1.1] This A.B, That C.D, et al, 2010
>
> [1.2] These A.B, That C.D, et al, 2012

References in chapter 2 should appear as

> [2.1] They A.B, That C.D, et al, 2010
>
> [2.2] Them A.B, That C.D, et al, 2012

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\input{./Chapters/Chapter1}
\input{./Chapters/Chapter2} 

\end{document}
```

---

```
%-----------Chapter1.tex----------
\chapter{CHAPTER 1}
This is the text \citep{Reference1} from chapter 1. Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts\citep{Reference2}  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} %
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES} %  adds "REFERENCES" to the table of content
\bibliography{Bibliography}
```

---

```
%-----------Chapter2.tex----------
\chapter{CHAPTER 2}
This is the text \citep{Reference3} from chapter 2 Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy\citep{Reference4} texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} %
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES} %  adds "REFERENCES" to the table of content
\bibliography{Bibliography}
```

---

**%Expected Output**

> **CHAPTER 1**
>
> This is the text[1.1] from chapter 1 Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy[1.2] texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts
>
> **Reference**
>
> [1.1] This A.B, That C.D, et al, 2010
>
> [1.2] These A.B, That C.D, et al, 2012
>
> **CHAPTER 2**
>
> This is the text[2.1] from chapter 2 Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy[2.2] texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts  Dummy texts Dummy texts
>
> **Reference**
>
> [2.1] They A.B, That C.D, et al, 2010
>
> [2.2] Them A.B, That C.D, et al, 2012

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your tagged your question with `biblatex` and `natbib`. Which package do you use? Please provide a mwe.

Comment: I don't know how to implement it. I am asking a question. Has anyone done this before? I simply want my citations to appear prefixed with the chapter number. Usually citations appear as [1],[2] etc. I want mine to have[1.1], [1.2]  depending on the chapter number

Comment: It is important to know which style do you use. Related to this there are various possibilities. `biblatex` offers `refsection` but it can't work with `chapterbib` or `bibunits`.

Answer (score 4):

You are working with `chapterbib` and `natbib`. As recommend in the documentation you should include your chapter files by `\include` instead of `\input`. `\include` provides a separate aux file which is used by `chapterbib`.

The package `chapterbib` provides the command `\CitationPrefix` which is unfortunately incompatible with `natbib`. However you can use this command with a small hack (shown in the example below.

The example needs an extra bibtex compilation for every chapter. I simplified the compilation steps by `arara` as shown in the MWE.

```
% arara: pdflatex:
% arara: bibtex:  { files: [Chapter1 , Chapter2] }
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Chapter1.tex}
%-----------Chapter1.tex----------
\chapter{CHAPTER 1}
This is the text \citep{knuth79}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{Bibliography}  
\end{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{Chapter2.tex}
%-----------Chapter2.tex----------
\chapter{CHAPTER 2}
This is the text \citep{goossens93}

Dummy texts  Dummy \citep{lamport94}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} %
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{Bibliography.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
    title = "The Latex Companion A",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"

}

@book{knuth79,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
        title = "Tex and Metafont, New Directions in Typesetting",
    year = {1979{(}1950{)}},
    publisher = "American Mathematical Society and Digital Press",
    address = "Stanford"
}

@book{lamport94,
    author = "Leslie Lamport",
    title = "Latex: A Document Preparation System",
    year = "1994",
    edition = "Second",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[sectionbib,square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\makeatletter
\let\@cb@insertprefix\relax
\def\@biblabel#1{[\@CitationPrefix#1]}
\def\NAT@open{[\@CitationPrefix}
\makeatother


\CitationPrefix{\thechapter.}

\begin{document}

\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am sort of confused, in what file am I supposed to put \RequirePackage{filecontents}. I am working with Texstudio

Comment: @I-YourOrLadeji: The package `filecontents` and the environment `filecontents` are only writing the files. If you compile this example with pdflatex the first time the files `Chapter1.tex`, `Chapter2.tex` and `Bibliography.bib` are generated.

Comment: Thanks alot, I find your suggestions very very useful and looks like it's drawing me closer to the expected solution. I have created a file main.tex , chapter1.tex, and chapter2.tex. Issued latex, bibtex, latex, latex..and got references like [1.?], [2.?] but no reference listing. I have cleaned .aux and recomplied but the same issue persists. I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Finally got it WORKING!!!! I forgot to issue bibtex on each of chapter1.tex and chapter2.tex